# Iterate elements of array without using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have an array with 1 million positive or negative values.

```
A=[1.3,4,5,6.4,-0.3,-2,-----]
```

I have to replace the values with 0 if the elements are negative and 1 if the element is positive.

I don't want to use it for a loop as it is taking a lot of time.

This is my current code:

```
 for i in range(len(arr)):
     if arr[i] > 0:
         arr[i] = 1
     else:
         arr[i] = 0
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *I don't want to use it for a loop as it is taking a lot of time* there may be ways to speed up your code, but there's no way to avoid a loop.

Comment: `dataframe` is a name of a data structure used in `pandas` library.  It's not in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and use the following code

```
arr = [1 if v > 0 else 0 for v in arr]
```

Comment: Where there is a `for` - there is a `loop`. It's just a "cooler" way to write a loop.

Comment: I invite you to show us a loop-less version. One way or another there will be a loop - either explicitly or hidden in a numpy function, for example.

Comment: Even if there wasn't (and there is, by transforming it to a `numpy` array for example), it doesn't mean that list comperhension should be considered a non-loop solution.

Comment: @Aryerez although it is not a non-loop solution it should still help, because it is a lot faster and uses no library. If you are fine using numpy as an extra library you should take it, because this will be the fastest solution

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1.3,4,5,6.4,-0.3,-2])
arr = np.where(arr > 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without numpy. But instead [list comprehension](https://www.pythoncentral.io/list-comprehension-in-python/)

```
arr = [0 if a < 0 else 1 for a in arr]
```

Comment: Where there is a `for` - there is a `loop`. It's just a "cooler" way to write a loop.

Comment: @Aryerez have a look at the link I posted. List comprehensions are a lot faster than standard for loops, because the line needs to be only interpredet once and not every time the for loops reaches it

Comment: @UliSotschok In CPython, list comprehensions are faster because they don't have to call the `append` function, they use the bytecode instruction LIST_APPEND instead. I'm not sure what you mean by "needs to be only interpredet once", CPython is compiled to bytecode, the bytecode within the loop will be executed for each iteration either way. You can compare them with `dis.dis` to check the bytecode generated for  a loop vs list comprehension, it is mostly the same except for LIST_APPEND instead of an `append` function call.